# iOS - SwiftUI update text when location changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working with SwiftUI and a CLLocationManager. Here is my LocationModel:

```
class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
  
  @Published var userLatitude: Double = 0
  @Published var userLongitude: Double = 0
  @Published var userTown: String = ""
    var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
  
  private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }
}

extension LocationViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    struct ReversedGeoLocation {
        let name: String            // eg. Apple Inc.
        let streetName: String      // eg. Infinite Loop
        let streetNumber: String    // eg. 1
        let city: String            // eg. Cupertino
        let state: String           // eg. CA
        let zipCode: String         // eg. 95014
        let country: String         // eg. United States
        let isoCountryCode: String  // eg. US

        var formattedAddress: String {
            return """
            \(name),
            \(streetNumber) \(streetName),
            \(city), \(state) \(zipCode)
            \(country)
            """
        }

        // Handle optionals as needed
        init(with placemark: CLPlacemark) {
            self.name           = placemark.name ?? ""
            self.streetName     = placemark.thoroughfare ?? ""
            self.streetNumber   = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
            self.city           = placemark.locality ?? ""
            self.state          = placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""
            self.zipCode        = placemark.postalCode ?? ""
            self.country        = placemark.country ?? ""
            self.isoCountryCode = placemark.isoCountryCode ?? ""
        }
    }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
    userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    userTown = getTown(lat: CLLocationDegrees.init(userLatitude), long: CLLocationDegrees.init(userLongitude))

    print(location)
  }
    
    func getTown(lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) -> String
    {
        var town = ""
        let location = CLLocation.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in

            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unexpected Error"
                print("Unable to reverse geocode the given location. Error: \(errorString)")
                return
            }

            let reversedGeoLocation = ReversedGeoLocation(with: placemark)
            print(reversedGeoLocation.city)
            
            town = reversedGeoLocation.city
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        
        return town
    }
}
```

Now I would like to display the current coordinates and the city, but the city is just not being displayed, seems that the variable is not being updated properly. How to do that? Here is my view:

```
@ObservedObject var locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()

    var latitude: Double  { return(locationViewModel.userLatitude ) }
    var longitude: Double { return(locationViewModel.userLongitude ) }
    var town: String { return(locationViewModel.userTown) }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Town: \(town)")
            Text("Latitude: \(latitude)")
            Text("Longitude: \(longitude)")
        }
    }
```

I do not completely understand how to pass the updated variable into the view when the location changes or when the completion of the getTown functions closes.

Comment: if you are using `self.objectWillChange.send()`, you want view to refresh only on a specific change, and not at every update. With current model you’re making updates every time, as properties are also marked `@published` which I don’t think is required, another thing is you don’t need to define this dependency explicitly `var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()`. You can directly have `self.objectWillChange.send()` in getTown function. For actual issue is lat and long being updated?

Comment: That is all fine and I can see the town being printed in getTown() (inside the location manager), but when I try to print it in the main view in a text label, it just appears to be empty. Do you know what is happening there?

Comment: Your `getTown` function will always return empty string, because you have `async` call inside that function, call after hitting  `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) ` line will go straight to return call, and return empty string. So your userTown is always `“”`. You can use `userTown` variable directly inside closure block, instead of `Town` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have made things more complicated than they need to be.  You don't need to explicitly publish changes in your model; The properties are marked as `@Published`, so changing them will automatically fire the property change.

The reason you aren't seeing updates in your view is because you have tried to use computed properties to access your model; This won't work.  There is nothing to consume the published changes to your model properties and nothing to tell the view that it should refresh.

If you simply access the view model properties directly in your `Text` views it will work the way you want.

Your final problems are related to reverse geocoding.  First, a reverse geocoding request completes asynchronously.  This means you can't `return town`.  Again, you can simply update the `userTown` property directly, dispatching onto the main queue since you can't guarantee that the reverse geocoding handler will be called on the main queue and all UI updates must be performed on the main queue.

Putting all of this together gets

```
class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
  
  @Published var userLatitude: Double = 0
  @Published var userLongitude: Double = 0
  @Published var userTown: String = ""
  
  private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }
}

extension LocationViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    struct ReversedGeoLocation {
        let name: String            // eg. Apple Inc.
        let streetName: String      // eg. Infinite Loop
        let streetNumber: String    // eg. 1
        let city: String            // eg. Cupertino
        let state: String           // eg. CA
        let zipCode: String         // eg. 95014
        let country: String         // eg. United States
        let isoCountryCode: String  // eg. US

        var formattedAddress: String {
            return """
            \(name),
            \(streetNumber) \(streetName),
            \(city), \(state) \(zipCode)
            \(country)
            """
        }

        // Handle optionals as needed
        init(with placemark: CLPlacemark) {
            self.name           = placemark.name ?? ""
            self.streetName     = placemark.thoroughfare ?? ""
            self.streetNumber   = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
            self.city           = placemark.locality ?? ""
            self.state          = placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""
            self.zipCode        = placemark.postalCode ?? ""
            self.country        = placemark.country ?? ""
            self.isoCountryCode = placemark.isoCountryCode ?? ""
        }
    }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
    userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    getTown(lat: CLLocationDegrees.init(userLatitude), long: CLLocationDegrees.init(userLongitude))

    print(location)
  }
    
    func getTown(lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) -> Void
    {
        let location = CLLocation.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in

            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unexpected Error"
                print("Unable to reverse geocode the given location. Error: \(errorString)")
                return
            }

            let reversedGeoLocation = ReversedGeoLocation(with: placemark)
            print(reversedGeoLocation.city)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userTown = reversedGeoLocation.city
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Town: \(locationViewModel.userTown)")
            Text("Latitude: \(locationViewModel.userLatitude)")
            Text("Longitude: \(locationViewModel.userLongitude)")
        }
    }
}
```

The final problem with reverse geocoding is that it is rate limited; you can only call it so many times in a period before you will start getting errors.  Location updates arrive about once per second, even when you aren't moving. Most of the time you will be needlessly looking up the same or almost the same location.

One approach is to check the distance travelled since the last reverse location look up and only perform a new look up if you exceed some threshold, say 500m

(We can also be a bit smarter with `getTown` - There is no point in splitting a location into latitude/longitude only to create a `CLLocation` in `getTown`)

```
private var lastTownLocation: CLLocation? = nil

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        
        if self.lastTownLocation == nil || self.lastTownLocation!.distance(from: location) > 500 {
            getTown(location)
        }
    }
    
    func getTown(_ location: CLLocation) -> Void
    {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unexpected Error"
                print("Unable to reverse geocode the given location. Error: \(errorString)")
                return
            }
            self.lastTownLocation = location
            let reversedGeoLocation = ReversedGeoLocation(with: placemark)
            print(reversedGeoLocation.city)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userTown = reversedGeoLocation.city
            }
        }
        
    }
```